# sql query error data not fetching data proprerly

Tags: mysql

The following SQL query doesn't return any results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM regtb 
WHERE name LIKE 'Karnataka' OR 
      email LIKE 'Karnataka' OR 
      mobile LIKE 'Karnataka' OR 
      city LIKE 'Karnataka' OR 
      ocity LIKE 'Karnataka' AND 
      date BETWEEN '2015-04-07' AND '2015-04-11' 
ORDER BY id
```

The queried table has the following structure:

id
email
password
name
city
mobile
exp
skill
ug
pg
phd
date

Any help is welcome

Comment: in this given dates onle one record of "Karnataka" is available but all records having "Karnataka" is fetching.

Comment: Can you please show us your `regtb` table values?

Comment: id  email  password  name  city    mobile  exp  skill  ug  pg  phd    date

Comment: @Rajeshk:- Edit your question and add the table structure there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM regtb 
WHERE (name LIKE 'Karnataka%' OR email LIKE 'Karnataka%' 
OR mobile LIKE 'Karnataka%' OR city LIKE 'Karnataka%' 
OR ocity LIKE 'Karnataka%') 
and (date between '2015-04-07' and '2015-04-11') 
ORDER BY id
```